# A list of lists, substract the values in each sub-list and store the results in new sub-lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list, that contains many sub-lists. Each sub-list, has two values. I want to substract the first value from the second value in each sub-list, and store the results in new lists.

Now those new lists are also sub-lists, of another list of lists.

So for example, `lists_of_lists1` is something like this:

```
lists_of_lists1 = [ran_list1, ran_list2, ran_list3, ran_list4, ran_list5, ran_list6,
          ran_list7,ran_list8]
```

And this is `ran_list1`, a sub-list. All sub-lists look similar to this.

```
[[34.39460533995712, 47.84539466004288],
 [33.095772478005635, 46.50422752199436],
 [36.66750709361337, 44.44360401749775],
 [33.33459042563053, 42.14689105585095],
 [36.638367322851444, 43.62250224236595],
 [36.465767572400296, 49.200899094266376],
 [32.220702473831686, 42.65929752616831],
 [34.31937169660605, 41.14216676493242],
 [31.198269305510344, 42.801730694489656],
 [31.216878962221035, 40.6092079943007],
 [28.465488368524227, 38.793770890735026],
 [34.50342917911651, 45.32990415421682]]
```

Now substract `ran_list1[1] - ran_list1[0]` (for each sublist in this manner), and the results store in here:

```
list_of_lists2 = [ran_subresult1 , ran_subresult2 , ran_subresult3 , ran_subresult4 ,
            ran_subresult5 , ran_subresult6 , ran_subresult7, ran_subresult8]
```

So `ran_subresult1`, is an empty list that the results of `ran_list1[1] - ran_list1[0]` would be store in it, and `ran_subresult2` would store the resuls of `ran_list2[1] - ran_list2[0]`, and so on...

My try of this look like this:

```
for i in lists_of_lists1:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        list_of_lists2[j].append(lists_of_lists1[j][1] - lists_of_lists1[j][0])
```

I got a bit lost with the `i` and `j`, I guess I'm in the right direction but I'm still unable to do it. I'll appreciate some help with this. Thanks!

#### EDIT - This is the expected output. From `lists_of_lists1`, let's take the first sub-list as an example, which is `ran_list1`. The values inside `ran_list1` are pairs of numbers:

```
[[34.39460533995712, 47.84539466004288],
 [33.095772478005635, 46.50422752199436],
 [36.66750709361337, 44.44360401749775],
 [33.33459042563053, 42.14689105585095],
 [36.638367322851444, 43.62250224236595],
 [36.465767572400296, 49.200899094266376],
 [32.220702473831686, 42.65929752616831],
 [34.31937169660605, 41.14216676493242],
 [31.198269305510344, 42.801730694489656],
 [31.216878962221035, 40.6092079943007],
 [28.465488368524227, 38.793770890735026],
 [34.50342917911651, 45.32990415421682]]
```

Now substract in this manner:

```
47.84539466004288 - 34.39460533995712 = 13.451
46.50422752199436 - 33.095772478005635 = 13.409
```

And so on...

Now those results will be stored inside `ran_subresult1`, which is the first sub-list inside `list_of_lists2`.

Hence, `ran_subresult1` would be `[13.451, 13.409.....]`

And so on for each sub-list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/) for this, it makes dealing with multidimensional arrays so much easier and it is far more efficient (because it is written in C). To start off, you have to [install numpy](https://numpy.org/install/). Then, in your code, import it. The convention is to import it as np:

```
import numpy as np
```

Next we want to turn your list of lists into a numpy array. If your different `ran_list`s have different dimensions, you will have to treat them independently, which is what I'll do here. (If they all have the same shape, you can treat it as one 3-d array.) :

```
list_of_lists2 = []
for sub_list in lists_of_lists1:
    new_sub_list = np.array(sub_list)
    new_sub_list = new_sub_list[:,1] - new_sub_list[:,0]
    list_of_lists2.append(new_sub_list.tolist())
```

Here I have turned the numpy arrays back into nested lists but if you want to continue to do calculations with them it's probably better to keep them as numpy arrays.

Comment: Yes, all sub-lists in `lists_of_lists1` are the same size. I tried your code however this doesn't quit give me the output I need. I need to fill each sub-list inside the `list_of_lists2`, according to calculations inside `list_of_lists1`. This code yields and array, numpy array I guess.

Comment: Can you tell me what you would expect the output to be for the example you gave and what my suggestion gives you instead? It seems to work just fine for me

Comment: Firstly, I appreciate the help, so thanks! I don't really understand the output that I'm getting, but overall I'm not getting a filled list of lists. I mean, I just want that the substaction calculation, that is happening in each sub-list inside of `lists_of_lists1`, to be stored accordinly in the sub-lists of `list_of_lists2`. So the results of subtraction in the sub-list `ran_list1`, would be stored in `ran_subresult1`. What I'm getting is one big list with lists and numbers. I can edit my question to add the output of your code if it helps. I explained the subtraction in the question above

Comment: I edited the question. I added an example for what I want, hope this helps.

Comment: Ok so it is what I originally thought then, so my original code should work. When you use the code I posted and do print(list_of_lists2), what do you get? Because I get this:

[[13.450789320085761, 13.408455043988724, 7.776096923884381, 8.81230063022042, 6.984134919514503, 12.73513152186608, 10.438595052336623, 6.822795068326371, 11.603461388979312, 9.392329032079662, 10.328282522210799, 10.82647497510031]]

Comment: Yes you're right, I apologize I coppied the wrong names (the names I used here are not the names I actually use). Thank you and sorry for being a pain.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative approach for your MWE:

```py
main_list = [
    [
        [34.39460533995712, 47.84539466004288],
        [33.095772478005635, 46.50422752199436],
        [36.66750709361337, 44.44360401749775],
        [33.33459042563053, 42.14689105585095],
        [36.638367322851444, 43.62250224236595],
        [36.465767572400296, 49.200899094266376],
        [32.220702473831686, 42.65929752616831],
        [34.31937169660605, 41.14216676493242],
        [31.198269305510344, 42.801730694489656],
        [31.216878962221035, 40.6092079943007],
        [28.465488368524227, 38.793770890735026],
        [34.50342917911651, 45.32990415421682],
    ]
]

res_list = main_list.copy()
for i, main_i in enumerate(main_list):
    for j, main_i_j in enumerate(main_i):
        res_list[i][j] = [main_i_j[1] - main_i_j[0]]
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work. We first get each element of the list of lists (a list with length 2) and then append the difference between the latter lists (i) elements.

```py
list = [[1, 23], [3, 2], [32, 213], [2321, 23]]
res_list = []
for i in list:
    res_list.append((i[1]-i[0]))

print(res_list)
```

Comment: This is only for one list.. he asked for a list of lists.